# How to remove a row in an rGtkDataFrame based on a selection in a gtkTreeView

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk

I'm porting a GUI from gWidgets to RGtk2. A part of the gui is a list of files that should be used for the analysis. I would like to be able to select files from this list and pres a button to remove the selected files. I stripped version of it can be created with the following code.

When setMode is set to 'multiple' I get a list of path's to the selected rows when i run getSelectedRows. I am stuck on how to convert this into a way of removing these rows from the TreeModel. As I understand it is not directly possible to delete rows or columns in a TreeModel so I will have to extract the data, remove the selected rows, and then update the rGtkDataFrame with the new data?

Any help is appreciated...

best/
Thomas

```
filelist <- rGtkDataFrame(data.frame(Datafiles=character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
mainWindow <- gtkWindow(show=FALSE)
datafileSelect <- gtkHBox(FALSE, 5)
mainWindow$add(datafileSelect)
files <- gtkTreeView(filelist)
files$insertColumnWithAttributes(position=-1, title='MS datafiles', cell=gtkCellRendererText(), text=0)
files$setHeadersVisible(FALSE)
fileSelect <- files$getSelection()
fileSelect$setMode('multiple')
datafileSelect$packStart(files)
datafileSelectButtons <- gtkVBox(FALSE, 5)
datafileSelect$packStart(datafileSelectButtons, expand=FALSE, fill=FALSE)
fileAddButton <- gtkButton(label='Add')
gSignalConnect(fileAddButton, 'clicked', f=function(widget, ...){
    file <- gtkFileChooserDialog(title='Select MS datafiles', parent=mainWindow, action='open', 'gtk-ok', GtkResponseType['ok'], 'gtk-cancel', GtkResponseType['cancel'], show=FALSE)
    file['select-multiple'] <- TRUE
    gSignalConnect(file, 'response', f=function(dialog, response, data){
        if(response == GtkResponseType['ok']){
          files <- as.character(dialog$getFilenames())
          filelist$appendRows(data.frame(Datafiles=files, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
          setwd(dirname(files[1]))
        }
        dialog$destroy()
        })
    file$show()
    })
fileRemoveButton <- gtkButton(label='Remove')
gSignalConnect(fileRemoveButton, 'clicked', f=function(widget, ...){
    selected <- fileSelect$getSelectedRows()
    })
datafileSelectButtons$packStart(fileAddButton, expand=FALSE, fill=FALSE)
datafileSelectButtons$packStart(fileRemoveButton, expand=FALSE, fill=FALSE)
mainWindow$setDefaultSize(250, 300)
mainWindow$show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I figured it out...

gtkTreePathToString function returns the index of the selections and than it's an easy task updating the TreeModel in rGtkDataFrame. The gSignalConnect for the remove button is thus:

```
gSignalConnect(fileRemoveButton, 'clicked', f=function(widget, ...){
    selected <- sapply(fileSelect$getSelectedRows()$retval, function(x) as.numeric(x$toString())+1)
    filelist$setFrame(filelist[-selected, , drop=FALSE])
    })
```